# Function triggered when a new List element is added

Tags: c#, list, count

I keep looking for a way of triggering a function in my code only after a List element is added, but i can't find any info.

I am thinking to create yet another List (see code) with the values of the `List.Count`, but that's how I got to 15 lists...

Is there a better way?

Thank you

```
private List<int>       ListCountH;
...
ListCountH = new List<int>();
...
if (!LHsDmiAdd && b > 1 && HSwDMI[b-1] - HSwDMI[b] > 0.001 && HSwDMI[b-1] - HSwDMI[b-2] > 0.001)
{
  LastHSwDMI.Add(HSwDMI[b-1]);
  listCountLH = LastHSwDMI.Count;
  ListCountH.Add(listCountLH);   
  j++;
}
...
if (ListCountH[j-1] > ListCountH[j-2]) 
{
  // Logic triggered after ListCountH increase
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, though:

```
var colL = new ObservableCollection<int>(ListCountL);
colL.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{ 
   if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
      // This code never triggers, but in the previous code it did after 
      // if (ListCountH[j-1] > ListCountH[j-2])                         
      if (k > 1 && c > 1 && (lowSwBarDiffA <= BarDiff || lowSwBarDiffB <= BarDiff))
        {
          if (!posDiv && ((LastLSwDMI[k-1] - LastLSwDMI[k-2] > 0.001 && LastLSwDMIprice[k-2] - LastLSwDMIprice[k-1] > TickSize)   
        || (LSwDMI[c-1] - LastLSwDMI[k-1] > 0.001 && LastLSwDMIprice[k-1] - LSwDMIprice[c-1] > TickSize)))  
            posDiv = true;  
         else
            posDiv = false;
         }
};
```

This method throws a lot of compiling errors as well when I try to declare the event handler:

```
public class Divergence5min : Strategy
{
   private MyList<int>      ListCountL, ListCountLastL;
   ...
  else if (State == State.Configure)                
  {
     ListCountL             = new MyList<int>();    
     ListCountLastL         = new MyList<int>();
  }

class MyList<T> : List<T> // Nested inside Divergence5min
{           
   public event Action<T> ItemAdded;            
   public new void Add(T obj)
   {                
     base.Add(obj);             
     if(ItemAdded != null)              
        ItemAdded.Invoke(obj);
   }
}

private void LookAfterLastLow()
{
    ListCountLastL.ItemAdded += AddItemEventHandler;
    void AddItemEventHandler()
    {   // The code I need executed after an item is added to ListCountLastL list
        if(listCountLL > 1)
        {       
            lastBarL = LastLSwDMIbar[k-1] + n;
            if (n <= 5)
            {
                newLastLowPrice = Lows[0].GetValueAt(lastBarL);
                if (newLastLowPrice < LastLSwDMIprice[k-1])
                {
                    LastLSwDMIprice[k-1] = newLastLowPrice;
                    newLastLowBar = lastBarL;
                    LastLSwDMIpriceBar[k-1] = newLastLowBar;
                    lowSwBarDiffB = Math.Abs(newLastLowBar - LastLSwDMIbar[k-1]);   
                    PrintLookAfterLow();                            
                }
                n++;
             }
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it C#?

Comment: That is C#, indeed

Comment: The most common way to "trigger a function" is to *call it*. Are you able to modify the code to call the function after calling the list's `Add` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should then encapsulate "adding" logic in a method:

```
public void AddElementToList(int element)
{
  ListCountH.Add(element);
  // your logic goes here
}
```

or you could define an `Add` event in your class and raise it upon adding element to a list, which again should be encapsulated in separate method:

```
public void AddElementToList(int element)
{
  ListCountH.Add(element);
  AddEvent?.Invoke();
}
```

Or you could write class wrapping `List` exposing special `Add` method and adding event and use that class instead of `List`.

EDIT: You should take a look at [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) :)

Example of usage:

```
// Have to include this using
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
```

Usage:

```
var ol = new ObservableCollection<int>();
ol.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
  if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    Console.WriteLine("Item added!");
};
```

Comment: Hey Michael, can you give a quick example of how `ObservableCollection` solves the listed problem as compared to `List` ?

Comment: @EtherDragon Done :)

Comment: Michal, can you please explain why would that be better than my solution?

Comment: @SorinPascu Because the class is specially designed for that scenario, so the code is easier to reaad and maintain. And you don't need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @Sorin Pascu if it’s not clear, you can define a function that occurs every time an Item is added, so you just need to put your own logic where Console.WriteLine("Item added!"); is. Like Console.WriteLine($"Item: {s.ToString()} added”);

Comment: Michal, I'm not sure I understand this Collection thing, but I am still not able to find a better solution, so I would appreciate if you could explain what is (s,e) in that syntax and what does the " e " do and what happens to " s " ? Many thanks

Comment: @SorinPascu `(s.e) => {...}` is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) and `s, e` are parameters. This is meant to match [event handler signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.oncollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1_OnCollectionChanged_System_Collections_Specialized_NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs_)

Answer (score 3):

You could turn your `List<int>` into a `BindingList<int>` like so:

```
BindingList<int> boundList = new BindingList<int>(ListCountH);
```

`BindingList<int>` implements `IBindingList<int>`, which has a `ListChanged` event handler.
So create a ListChangedEventHandler:

```
public void BoundList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
    //use e.ListChangedType property to determine if a row was added
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded) {
    ...Do Your Work Here...
    }
}
```

Then add the handler to your BindingList's ListChanged event:

```
boundList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(BoundList_ListChanged);
```

Edit: Depending what you are using the list for, the current top answer may be better, as ObservableCollection is far more lightweight if all you need to know is when an item is added. However, BindingList has some advantages with items that support INotifyPropertyChanged (it can propagate the items' PropertyChanged events to its ListChanged event), or if you need support for Sorting, Searching, or ReadOnly lists.

EDIT: made it more clear that the event handler is handling the `BindingList`'s `ListChanged` event, previously I named the function after the other list, which would not be used in this implementation.

Comment: Zaelin, how would that be better than my way of just using another list?

Comment: Well once you have the `BindingList<int>` by passing your other list into the constructor, you don't need to access the other list any more - the BindingList copies the List's elements into it's internal collection. `BindingList<T>`, like `List<T>`, implements `ICollection<T>`, so you can use `BindingList.Add()` or `BindingList.Remove()` just like you would with the `List`. You can eliminate the list altogether by making `ListCountH` a `new BindingList<int>()` from the beginning. BindingList is specifically designed for this scenario, so the code will be cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the reason you named the BindingList `boundList` and the event handler `BoundList_ListChanged`? I struggle to understand the difference between lower and upper case.

Comment: It's simply a preference in naming convention. It's called camel casing, used to show the separation between words. The reason I make `boundList` lowercase and `BoundList_ListChanged` uppercase is to distinguish between `fields` and `methods`. In practice, it's purely a matter of preference. But I also work in VB a lot, where parenthesis are not necessary for function calls with no parameters, so it's nice to have a quick visual distinction between a function and a field/property

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own List class (Ex: `MyList<T>`) and add an event for when an item is added to the list.

```cs
class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    //  Add an event that will be triggered after adding an item
    public event Action<T> ItemAdded;

    //  Override the add method
    public new void Add(T obj)
    {
        //  Call the parent add action
        base.Add(obj);

        //  Trigger the event
        ItemAdded?.Invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

Using this class, you can subscribe as many functions as you want to the event and all the subscribed actions will be invoked when an item is added.

Try the event:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    //  Create empty list
    MyList<string> list = new MyList<string>();

    //  Create a dummy action to display the added item
    void AddItemEventHandler(string item) => Console.WriteLine(item);

    //  Subscribe to the event
    list.ItemAdded += AddItemEventHandler;

    //  Add items to trigger the event
    list.Add("Hello");
    list.Add("Hola");
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hola
```

Comment: can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong when I try to implement your method, as per my last edit of the question? Thank you

Comment: The ItemAdded event is using an Action<T> delegate, which means that Functions with 1 parameter of type of T can subscribe to the event. Your AddItemEventHandler() has 0 parameters, which is why you cannot subscribe to an event of Action<T>. You can add a parameter to AddItemEventHandler(int item) or change the delegate to a parameterless action: event Action ItemAdded;.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I've got it... eventually

```
public class Divergence5min : Strategy
{
 private ObservableCollection <double> LastLSwDMI;
....
 LastLSwDMI = new ObservableCollection <double>();

...
 private void LookAfterLastLow()
 {
   LastLSwDMI.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => 
   {
     if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
     {                  
        if(/*!LSwDMIbool &&*/ listCountLL > 1 && BarsInProgress == 0 && IsFirstTickOfBar)
        {       
           lastBarL = LastLSwDMIbar[k-1] + n;
           if (n <= 5)
           {
              newLastLowPrice = Lows[0].GetValueAt(lastBarL);
              if (newLastLowPrice < LastLSwDMIprice[k-1])
              {
                 LastLSwDMIprice[k-1] = newLastLowPrice;
                 newLastLowBar = lastBarL;
                 LastLSwDMIpriceBar[k-1] = newLastLowBar;
                 lowSwBarDiffB = Math.Abs(newLastLowBar - LastLSwDMIbar[k-1]);                                                          
              }
              n++;
            }               
         }
      }
    };
  }
}
```